# Is there anyway to insert only unique entries into a pivot table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have tried to use INSERT IGNORE but still I can see that when I runs the query again. It still inserts the records. I don't want to insert duplicate records in there.

Can anyone help me out?

```
INSERT INTO enquiry_location_status 
        (enquiry_id, 
         location_id, 
         enquiry_status) 
SELECT we.id          AS enquiry_id, 
   wl.location_id AS location_id, 
   we.status      AS enquiry_status 
FROM   enquiry we 
   LEFT JOIN wishlist w 
          ON w.enquiry_id = we.id 
   LEFT JOIN wishlist_location wl 
          ON wl.wishlist_id = w.id 
WHERE  wl.wishlist_id IS NOT NULL;
```

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `enquiry_location_status` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `enquiry_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `enquiry_status` varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `enquiry_location_status`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `enquiry_location_status`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Here is a screenshot how my pivot table data looks like: 
[image]

I have tried this, it seems to be working but it's very slow. It's taking 80 seconds for 40 K+ records just.

```
INSERT INTO enquiry_location_status 
            (enquiry_id, 
             location_id, 
             enquiry_status) 
SELECT we.id          AS enquiry_id, 
       wl.location_id AS location_id, 
       we.status      AS enquiry_status 
FROM   enquiry we 
       LEFT JOIN wishlist w 
              ON w.enquiry_id = we.id 
       LEFT JOIN wishlist_location wl 
              ON wl.wishlist_id = w.id 
WHERE  wl.wishlist_id IS NOT NULL 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT els.enquiry_id, 
                              els.location_id, 
                              els.enquiry_status 
                       FROM   enquiry_location_status els 
                       WHERE  els.enquiry_id = we.id 
                              AND els.location_id = wl.location_id 
                              AND els.enquiry_status = we.status)
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please add your table definition.

Comment: @P.Salmon: I have added the table definition.

Comment: You need a `UNIQUE` column and use the `INSERT IGNORE INTO`. Read [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/)

Comment: I have updated the question with some new code, that seems to be working but it's very slow. Is there any solution?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the Primary key queries. I have updated my whole table definition.